# Microsoft Azure iot-hub: The measured senosor values sent via device to iot-hub cannot be read stored Json data

Tags: json, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

We are using a data acquisition system as a device and send some signals values via MQTT protocol into a container which is assigned to an iot-hub. The connection works well between device and iot-hub, and we receive some JSON data. When we open a JSON data, We cannot read the temperature values in "Body" inside the JSON data, since they are encoded. I would be thankful if you tell us, how we should automatically convert the JSON data to a proper format so that we could read the values in numbers?

Please find below three of our code's lines in JSON Data. The rest of the lines are the same, but they are encoded differently.

> {"EnqueuedTimeUtc":"2022-02-09T10:00:30.8600000Z","Properties":{"Sensor":""},"SystemProperties":{"connectionDeviceId":"Iba","connectionAuthMethod":"{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}","connectionDeviceGenerationId":"637799949903534194","enqueuedTime":"2022-02-09T10:00:30.8600000Z"},"Body":"My42MjI3NTQ="}

> {"EnqueuedTimeUtc":"2022-02-09T10:00:30.8750000Z","Properties":{"Sensor":""},"SystemProperties":{"connectionDeviceId":"Iba","connectionAuthMethod":"{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}","connectionDeviceGenerationId":"637799949903534194","enqueuedTime":"2022-02-09T10:00:30.8750000Z"},"Body":"My42ODEyNDY="}

> {"EnqueuedTimeUtc":"2022-02-09T10:00:30.9070000Z","Properties":{"Sensor":""},"SystemProperties":{"connectionDeviceId":"Iba","connectionAuthMethod":"{"scope":"device","type":"sas","issuer":"iothub","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}","connectionDeviceGenerationId":"637799949903534194","enqueuedTime":"2022-02-09T10:00:30.9070000Z"},"Body":"My43Mzk1OTI="}

Thanks in advance!

Br
Masoud

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you should add to the message topic two parameters such as the content-type (ct) and content-encoding (ce) like is shown in the following example:

```
 devices/device1/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do not see any place to add these parameters in the settings of the device. I can see just "Basic Topic Path: devices/iotdevice/messages/events" in the settings, when I add your code, then the connection does not work anymore. Should I add it in Microsoft azure? if yes, could you please tell me where? Br
Masoud

Comment: based on your messages, the deviceId is *Iba*, so your Topic settings should be: **devices/Iba/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8**

Comment: another way to populate these message properties is in your device code, when the telemetry data is sent (published on the topic)

Comment: Sorry, while replying you, I wrote the name of the device wrongly. I tried it and unfortunately it does not work. When I tried it, I receive an error and the connection does not work anymore. There are some windows and parameters in the settings of the data acquisition system, and it has no code to add your code.

Comment: Can we change the JSON code in Iot-hub maybe? when we get the messages, then convert and store them in containers ?